# AsyncHttpClient download large Pdf files out of memory error

Tags: android

I'm building my first Android app and have run into a little problem. Using AsyncHttpClient to download Pdf files I get

```
      "E/dalvikvm-heap(30871): Out of memory on a 21893326-byte allocation."
```

errors on anything larger than 15 Mb. Files up to 15 Mb download just fine. Are there any settings that can resolve this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there any settings that can resolve this?

Not really. Assuming that you are using `BinaryHttpResponseHandler`, it will give you the entire file in memory, which will not be possible for larger files.

You would need to create your own version of `BinaryHttpResponseHandler` with a modified `sendResponseMessage()` method, one that streams the results directly to a file. Or, find another HTTP client library that does this for you.

Comment: I've been using your projects for some understanding. Camre->Preview is one of them. I am grateful for your help. There is something that I want to know through your enlightenment, can we use some callback mechanism or some listener to get file uploading progress? I am using AsyncHttpClient (loopj). Seems this question is also related to AsyncHttpClient (loopj). Any help or guidance would be very helpful.

Comment: @FahadIshaque: I have not used AsyncHttpClient -- I just read the source code to determine what your problem was. If you have further questions about AsyncHttpClient, you are probably better served contacting its author.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Camare->Preview is a great example, please could you just add a check for camera availability (dedicated or front) in it. As I have tested it and works fine on all of my device except for Nexus7 due to obvious reason(no dedicated camera). Thanks! Cheers!

Comment: @FahadIshaque: I plan, in the coming months, to create a reusable component for camera work, and I will try to remember to take your request into account.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Not what I wanted to hear but at least I have some clarity. How would you approach this?

Comment: @BigHonkingDeal: Pretty much as I wrote in the last paragraph of my answer. All `BinaryHttpResponseHandler` does is wrap around an `HttpResponse`, and you can get the `InputStream` of the HTTP response payload via that `HttpResponse`. Just use that with the classic "read a chunk, write a chunk" process to copy from stream to stream.